# Application Design Patterns AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, design-patterns, data-binding, flash-builder

just thought I would share something I have found to help delivering data across an application I am wondering what others think about this I wanted to have a way to capture event bubbling up back down to other components but in a way that it would make it easy to use anywhere in may app so this is what i came up with.

I Extend the Application class and wrap in an abstract function registering a function of any component anywhere and capture it at the top most level and pass to where ever i chose to.

```
public class AxApplication extends Application
{
    public var ___registeredEvents:Array = new Array();
    public var ___registeredFunctions:Array = new Array();
    function AxApplication()
    {
        super();
    }
    public function localRegisterForEvent(e:Event,func:*,caller:*):void
    {
        caller.addEventListener(e.type,localCallerEventHandler,true,3);
        caller.addEventListener(e.type,localCallerEventHandler,false,3);
        ___registeredEvents.push(e);
        ___registeredFunctions.push(func);
    }
    public function localCallerEventHandler(e:*):void
    {
        if(e!=null)
        {
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i<  ___registeredEvents.length; i++)
            {
                if(e.type == ___registeredEvents[i].type)
                {
                    ___registeredFunctions[i](e);
```

//the registered function gets called
//there no garbage collection implemented!

```
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I guess one thing i should have mentioned is how to use it you can use it like this:

Comment: AxApplication(this.parentApplication).localRegisterForEvent(new Event(Event.SOME_EVENT),someFunctionHandler,callingObject); The  calling object being the one who will be outputting the event as long as you register that object once in the app it will pass it back anywhere without any coding for getting data more then once.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not a very useful solution. Why? Because you scatter AxApplication references around the application. Views and Model instance don't need any references to the application at all. It would be better to to implement a controller layer which uses a simple eventBus property, which could look like:

```
private static const _EVENT_BUS:IEventDispatcher = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

protected final function eventBus():IEventDispatcher {
  return _EVENT_BUS;
}
```

If you implement a base view controller/mediator (depending from which framework you're coming), you don't have any reference to non-framework classes at all, which makes it highly reusable. It is just a simple reuse of the Application singleton which you use to dispatch system wide events. You register listeners in the view controller/mediator and update the views or models accordingly. RobotLegs for example uses a system wide event dispatcher as well.

Why not just using the parentApplication approach? Because you can't implement tests (the generated test-runner of IDEs won't extend your AxApplication) or just yank the components/models in a different application - that is basically not possible.

Comment: Ok nice, I did not know about the event bus witch was my reason for coming out and throwing my idea out because i need to find a more sophisticated to manage event and data without have to code every layer or dealing with event dispatching.  But getting back to your response since at the time I was considering the flexGlobals object and the reference on the usage of it is rather slim, if i remember correctly the flexGlobals.TopLevelApplication is a property of the application that you can explicitly define as being an abstract class/object that will sit between your code and the framework...

Comment: This object will have persistent focus on the application function calls throughout the life cycle of the application? I must ask respectfully for you to contribute a small example of the user of the flexGlobals.TopLevelApplication. :) Thanks

Comment: The point of my solution is, that you're controller layer depends only on the eventBus property in order to work. All instances of a controller will use the same instance to dispatch events. But there is no more knowledge necessary compared to your solution. When you want to reuse certain aspects, the compiler will break because of the type cast ou need.

Comment: Also, in my solution you could add a set property for the bus and inject a reference to an IEventDispatcher. This makes it compatible to any dependency injection framework. When using a d.i. framework, you could use any instance you want, because it will be injected into the controllers and hide the concrete implementation of the dispatcher.

Comment: I don't understand the focus - aspect, you were thinking of.